# Python - leave only n items in a list

Tags: python, list

There are many ways to remove n items from the list, but I couldn't find a way to keep n items.

```
lst = ["ele1", "ele2", "ele3", "ele4", "ele5", "ele6", "ele7", "ele8", "ele9", "ele10"]
n = 5
lst = lst[:len(lst)-(len(lst)-n)]
print(lst)
```

So I tried to solve it in the same way as above, but the problem is that the value of 'lst' always changes in the work I am trying to do, so that method is not valid.

I want to know how to leave only n elements in a list and remove all elements after that.

Comment: at least add some expected output

Comment: `lst = lst[:n]` will keep the first n elements

Comment: Sembei Norimaki - Resolved. thank you

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: If the other elements truly aren't needed and modifying the original `list` (even seen through other aliases) is okay, `del lst[n:]` is better; it doesn't make a new `list` and replace the old (guaranteed new allocs and frees), it just chops off the unwanted elements directly (which at most requires a single shrinking realloc).

Comment: true, but since the OP was doing `lst = lst[:len(lst)-(len(lst)-n)]` I assumed that actually wanted to create a new list but was struggling about slicing. The funny part is that `len(lst)-(len(lst)-n)` can be written as `len(lst) - len(lst) + n ` giving as a result `n`

Comment: @anfwkdrn: A note: Do the math for your slice index calculation, replacing `len(lst)` with `x`. `x - (x - n)` expands the first `-` through the parentheses to make it `x - x + n`, where the `x`s clearly cancel out and you're left with `n`, you wrote `lst[:n]` the *really* long way). You basically never need to know the length of a `list` to slice it in any event (you can use negative indices to slice relative to the end of the `list` if that's needed, no need for `len` computation; if you wanted the last `n` elements for instance, you'd just do `lst[-n:]`, no need for `len(lst)`).

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: Heh, I was just writing a comment to point that out.

Comment: In fact, I omitted the explanation a bit. It's not just lst that changes, but the value of n also changes, and there are other conditions. To do it that way, I had to add a conditional statement. So, I thought it would be most efficient to simply leave only n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest/fastest solution is:

```
del lst[n:]
```

which tells it to delete any elements index `n` or above (implicitly keeping `0` through `n - 1`, a total of `n` elements).

If you must preserve the original `list` (e.g. maybe you received it as an argument, and it's poor form to change what they passed you most of the time), you can just reverse the approach (slice out what you want to keep, rather than remove what you want to discard) and do:

```
truncated = lst[:n]  # You have access to short form and long form
```

so you have both the long and short form, or if *you* don't need the original `list` anymore, but it might be aliased elsewhere and you want the aliases unmodified:

```
lst = lst[:n]  # Replaces your local alias, but leaves other aliases unchanged
```

Answer (score 0):

very similar to the solution of ShadowRanger, but using a slice assignment on the left hand side of the assigment oparator:

```
lst[n:] = []
```

Comment: Yar, this is exactly equivalent to the `del lst[n:]` approach, aside from this approach requiring the creation and destruction of an empty `list` (using `lst[n:] = ()` would be a slight optimization, as the empty `tuple` is a singleton, so nothing needs to be created or destroyed, it just has to acquire and drop a reference to the empty `tuple`).